# How to get Google meet link thru google calendar api in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I want to create a line notify which can send the event detail from my google calendar everyday.
I can get the title, description, location...etc, but I don't see the conference data in calendar API.
I use Google Apps Script to run the code.
Here is my code.

```
const Now = new Date();
const Start = new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
const End =  new Date(new Date().setHours(23, 59, 59, 999));
const calendarData = calendar.getEvents(Start, End);

function Notify() {
  var NotifyContents = '';
  var i = 1;
  calendarData.forEach(item =>{
      if (Now <= item.getStartTime()) {
        NotifyContents += (item.getTitle() != "") ? ("\n" + i+". "+ item.getTitle() + "\n") : ("\n\nNo Title\n");
        NotifyContents += (item.getDescription() != "") ? item.getDescription() + "\n" : "";
        NotifyContents += (item.getStartTime() != "" && item.getEndTime() != "") ? "Time：" + item.getStartTime().toLocaleTimeString() + "-" + item.getEndTime().toLocaleTimeString() + "\n": "";
        NotifyContents += (item.getconferencedata() != "") ? ("\n" + i+". "+ item.getconferencedata()) : ("No Conference\n");
        i++;
      }
    }
  )
  if (typeof NotifyContents === 'string' && NotifyContents.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  NotifyTokens.forEach(function(value){
    UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify", {
      "method"  : "post",
      "payload" : {"message" : NotifyContents},
      "headers" : {"Authorization" : "Bearer " + value}
    });
  });
}
```

Reference - [Calendar API Link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to retrieve the meet link from the event, it seems that in the current stage, Calendar API is required to be used. When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Calendar API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

##### From:

```
var NotifyContents = '';
var i = 1;
calendarData.forEach(item => {
  if (Now <= item.getStartTime()) {
    NotifyContents += (item.getTitle() != "") ? ("\n" + i + ". " + item.getTitle() + "\n") : ("\n\nNo Title\n");
    NotifyContents += (item.getDescription() != "") ? item.getDescription() + "\n" : "";
    NotifyContents += (item.getStartTime() != "" && item.getEndTime() != "") ? "Time：" + item.getStartTime().toLocaleTimeString() + "-" + item.getEndTime().toLocaleTimeString() + "\n" : "";
    NotifyContents += (item.getconferencedata() != "") ? ("\n" + i + ". " + item.getconferencedata()) : ("No Conference\n");
    i++;
  }
}
)
```

##### To:

```
const eventList = Calendar.Events.list(calendar.getId(), { timeMin: Start.toISOString(), timeMax: End.toISOString(), maxResults: 2500 }).items.reduce((o, e) => (o[e.id] = e.conferenceData.entryPoints.map(({ uri }) => uri).join(","), o), {});
var NotifyContents = '';
var i = 1;
calendarData.forEach(item => {
  if (Now <= item.getStartTime()) {
    NotifyContents += (item.getTitle() != "") ? ("\n" + i + ". " + item.getTitle() + "\n") : ("\n\nNo Title\n");
    NotifyContents += (item.getDescription() != "") ? item.getDescription() + "\n" : "";
    NotifyContents += (item.getStartTime() != "" && item.getEndTime() != "") ? "Time：" + item.getStartTime().toLocaleTimeString() + "-" + item.getEndTime().toLocaleTimeString() + "\n" : "";
    var eventId = item.getId().split("@")[0];
    NotifyContents += eventList[eventId] != "" ? ("\n" + i + ". " + eventList[eventId]) : ("No Conference\n");
    i++;
  }
});
```

- In this modification, it supposes that `calendar` has already been declaread. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list)

Comment: @Jack Chou Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: I get the error... if event doesn't have conference, how to modify the script. (Sorry.. I'm poor at javascript)
Error log: 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'entryPoints' of undefined`

Comment: @Jack Chou About your new question of `I get the error... if event doesn't have conference, how to modify the script. (Sorry.. I'm poor at javascript) Error log: TypeError: Cannot read property 'entryPoints' of undefined`, in this case, how about modifying `const eventList = Calendar.Events.list(calendar.getId(), { timeMin: Start.toISOString(), timeMax: End.toISOString(), maxResults: 2500 }).items.reduce((o, e) => (o[e.id] = e.conferenceData.entryPoints.map(({ uri }) => uri).join(","), o), {});
var NotifyContents = '';` as follows?

Comment: @Jack Chou `const eventList = Calendar.Events.list(calendar.getId(), { timeMin: Start.toISOString(), timeMax: End.toISOString(), maxResults: 2500 }).items.reduce((o, e) => (o[e.id] = e.conferenceData ? e.conferenceData.entryPoints.map(({ uri }) => uri).join(",") : "", o), {});`

Comment: Many thank!!!   It's really kind of you for helping me!!!!!!!